# Ionic 2 Form goes up when keyboard shows

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using latest version of ionic 2.
My code has a `<ion-content padding><form></form></ion-content>` with a text input inside of it. When I try to type something in there on Android the whole page gets pushed upwards by the keyboard.

**html file**

```
<ion-content class="login-screen" padding>
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()" novalidate>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button full type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <button ion-button clear full outline type="button" (click)="openModal()">Forgot Password?</button>
</ion-content>
```

is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 45):

This all should be fixed in the RC4 (soon). That being said, to disable the scroll when input is focused, add this to your config object (in the `@NgModule`):

```
...
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        scrollAssist: false, 
        autoFocusAssist: false
    }),
    ...
],
...
```

A very good explanation of those two properties can be found [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5432):

> Under Ionic2 defaults, however, there are additional features in place
>   attempting to both compensate for the keyboard slideover by adding
>   padding to the bottom of your content ('scrollAssist') and to keep the
>   focused input element within the viewport by scrolling back to it
>   ('autoFocusAssist'). Both scrollAssist and autoFocusAssist have nicely
>   implemented switches in config that just don't appear to have gotten
>   public documented yet.

You can also use the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` to stop the native browser from pushing/scrolling the content pane up and allow the keyboard to slide over and cover existing content:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
    Splashscreen.hide();

    Keyboard.disableScroll(false); // <- like this

    // ...
```

**UPDATE**

Just like @Luckylooke mentioned in the comments:

> Keyboard.disableScroll(), ios and windows supported

**UPDATE II**

As of Ionic 3.5.x seems like the keyboard still have some issues. I've found that the following configuration produces a better result (compared with the defaults) from the UI/UX point of view:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        //...
    ],
    imports: [
        //...
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
            scrollPadding: false,
            scrollAssist: true,
            autoFocusAssist: false
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

By keeping `scrollAssist: true` we avoid the input to be hidden by the keyboard if it's near the bottom of the page, and by setting `scrollPadding: false` we also avoid some weird bugs related to an empty white space after hiding the keyboard.

Comment: note: Keyboard.disableScroll(), ios and windows supported

Comment: Thanks @Luckylooke, I've added that information to the answer :)

Comment: Will the above solution works if the page has multiple input fields and a button on the footer?

Comment: @sebaferreras, issue still exists

Comment: I still get this too.

Comment: This works. However, sometimes when I am using an ion-footer, the ion-footer was still pushed upward and covers the input before a key is pressed. Once the key is pressed the input field will be visible. This scenario is occurring for, like, 20% probability.

Comment: How this will handle in Ionic4?

Comment: in ionic 4 this answer doesnt work unfortunately [disableScroll() was removed](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/blob/master/www/ios/keyboard.js#L89) also

Comment: nevermind solved it, was using `top` and some other properties that I removed and it worked

Answer (score 0):

there is some issues for inputs and forms with the scrolling like is mentioned [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6228) so i recommend wait to the next RC to get that fixed, cause its not your code fault's just ionic bug.

Comment: But i think there is some way to disabled scroll when input focused. but i don't know how its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to the .ts on this page

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.content.resize();
}
```

My scenario is: the keyboard is called on this page, but when you return to the previous page, the page will appear as a whole, and I try to solve it with this method, I use ionic2.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this properties to your ionicModule in app.module.ts. works for me.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      scrollAssist: false, 
      autoFocusAssist: false
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Open iOS workspace from iOS platform of Ionic project and write below method in MainViewController.m

```
/////////////--------------------------//////////////
/*
 *Description: this method was trigger by selector keyboarwillhide from notification
 */
-(void)keyboardWillHide
{
    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        WKWebView *webview = (WKWebView*)self.webView;
         for(UIView* v in webview.subviews){
            if([v isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"WKScrollView")]){
                UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView*)v;
                [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
             }
          }
     }
}
```

Call above method in viewDidLoad through NotificationCenter

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /**
     * observer notification when keyboard will hide
     */

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```