# ionic 3 -Keyboard pushes the whole screen up

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I build ionic 3 app.
I have inputs field and when I press on them to begin to type anything the screen changed..

before

[image]

when I press on any input field the screen changed(it's test also in real device)
[image]

Comment: Can you show the `Scss` code on that page's layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 Form goes up when keyboard shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161705/ionic-2-form-goes-up-when-keyboard-shows)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem by adding this style to app.scss:

```
    ion-grid {
      min-height: 100%;
     }
```

The keyboard resizes Ionic's grid system if you didn't define its minimum height.

Comment: it's worked but I set this style to ion-content instead of ion-grid.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the native keyboard to prevent the keyboard from pushing things up.

```
keyboard.disableScroll(bool);
```

[Ionic Native Keyboard Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/)