# Keyboard issues with Ionic3

Tags: keyboard, ionic3

I am experiences a problem with keyboard. I have a page with a list containing 5 input fields. When the keyboard shows the page pushes up and when the keyboard hides the page position remains the same. When I inspect it, shows that there is a `padding-bottom:300px` present even after the keyboard hides.
Is there any solution for the same? Please find the html code below

```
<ion-content padding #content>
<img src="assets/imgs/ic_tutorial_three.png" style="height:150px;width:150px">
<ion-card>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-end class="margin-bottom-none" *ngIf="validCurrentKey">
          <img src="assets/imgs/ic_tick.png" class="tick-button">
        </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Your Current PIN</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="PIN" (ionChange)='checkCurrentPassword($event)'></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Enter Your New PIN</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="PIN"  [(ngModel)]="newPin"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked>RE-Enter Your New PIN</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="PIN"  (ionChange)="validateNewPassword($event)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
<div class="bottom-button"> 
    <button ion-button round full class="submit-button"  (click)="goBack()" >UPDATE PIN</button>
</div>
```

I having the same issue with this question [ionic 3 -Keyboard pushes the whole screen up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436894/ionic-3-keyboard-pushes-the-whole-screen-up)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs because of scroll when input field get Focused.

To disable the scroll when input is focused, Add following code to "app.module.ts" file of your project:

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        scrollPadding: false,
        scrollAssist: false, 
        autoFocusAssist: false
    }),
    ...
],
```

Also checkout following link for detailed explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163695/6862286

Comment: I have done the same and followed the link. But the issue comes when the keyboard closes. The padding-bottom 300px remains there

Comment: Could you please verify the same?

Comment: I have verified it in a demo app and it is working fine.