# Keyboard pushes the input up and it dose not comes back to original

Tags: android, ionic3

When i tap on input keyboard opens and pushes the control up.
That is fine but when i tap outside the keyboard goes off and it take sometime to come to original position and sometimes it doesn’t come back to original position.
[Issue in motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbgfd.gif)
I have tried disabling keyboard scroll and setting auto assist=false in modules.
**Ionic info -**

```
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Misc:
    backend : pro
```

**My Code - login.html**

```
<ion-content class="login-background">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row responsive-sm>
      <ion-col text-center>
        <h1>Company Logo</h1>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row responsive-sm>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-list padding>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary"><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="Email" type="email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary"><ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="Password" type="password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <br>
          <ion-item text-center>
            <button ion-button color="secondary" large block>Login</button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**login.scss**

```
page-login {
  ion-grid {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
}
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Please check if **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161705/ionic-2-form-goes-up-when-keyboard-shows/41163695#41163695)** may help...

Comment: If i do that the keyboard overlaps the input which i don't want. I am okay with the content pushing up but the return is not smooth an sometimes it dose not come back to normal position.

Comment: In the *UPDATE II* I mention that `scrollPadding: false, scrollAssist: true, autoFocusAssist: false` will still avoid the input to be hidden by the keyboard, but it somehow improves the transitions. Were you able to test that specific configuration?