# Ionic fixed content at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, ionic3

I have created a login form for my app with ionic 3, when I toggle the keyboard the content at the bottom moves to the top part.

This is my design for the screen when keyboard is not toggled.
[image]

When the keyboard is toggled.

[image]

My html mockup

```
<ion-content text-center class="login">

    <!--top-->
    <form [formGroup]="valForm" (submit)="OnLogin($event, valForm.value)">
    <div padding class="animated fadeIn center-On-Screen" ion-fixed>
        <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.png">
        <ion-list padding>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="email" placeholder="E-mail"
                 class="form-control"  name="email" 
                 autocomplete="off" formControlName="email"
                required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"
                 name="password" 
                formControlName="password" required=""></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <div class="forgotpass" item-right (click)="Forgotpass()">Forgot password</div>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>


    </div>
        <div class="signin-content btn-holder" ion-fixed>
            <div class=" animated bounceInUp">
                <button ion-button block outline color="light" type="submit" [disabled]="!valForm.valid">Sign In</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!--footer-->
    <div class="footer-content btn-holder" ion-fixed>
        <div class=" animated bounceInUp">
            <button ion-button block color="facebook" (click)="doFbLogin()">Facebook</button>

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="footer-signup signup">
        <div class="animated bounceInUp">
            <a color="light" (click)="Register()">New Here?
                <strong>Sign Up</strong>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS for the positioning.

```
.signin-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
    width: 100%;
 }
.footer-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 12%;
    width: 100%;
}
.signup-content{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

How can I make it such that the content remain at the bottom.

My development environment.

```
cli packages: 

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.2
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
    ios-sim           : https://registry.npmjs.org/ios-sim/-/ios-sim-5.0.12.tgz 
    Node              : v8.5.0
    npm               : 5.5.1 
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
```

Have tried this solution from this link [Ionic native keyboard](https://gist.github.com/EvanWillms/8773f8cfa12f469fabf0bdd7a75723e7) plus the solution below editing the `config.xml` but still didn't fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 Form goes up when keyboard shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161705/ionic-2-form-goes-up-when-keyboard-shows)

Answer (score 1):

In your login.ts file add these:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public platform: Platform, public keyboard: Keyboard) {

}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    });
}
```

There's another solution:

Open your config.xml file and add the following line in the platform name="android" tag:

```
<platform name="android"> 
  <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity"> <activity windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /></edit-config>
  ...the rest of the android configs...
</platform>
```

Comment: I don't  have app.ts but main.ts

Comment: ahh.. sorry, please see updated answer. you can put it in login.ts

Comment: Am getting an error at `disableScroll` which states `Property 'disableScroll' does not exist on type 'Keyboard'`

Comment: thanks for your help, the solution doesn't work on ionic3 though. Still trying to find a fix for this.