# Ionic Iframe continuesly reload while typing

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3, ionic-native

I created a page with an iframe. The url that the iframe will render has some input fields. When I type something, it reload all the page and I can do nothing.

View

```
<ion-content no-padding>
 <iframe [src]="urlpaste()"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  my_url: any;
  constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer) {}

  urlpaste(){
    this.my_url = "http://example.com/";
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.my_url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may have to do with the resize event(s) generated from clicking into the input field, in which case a zoom in happens or the on-screen keyboard pushes the form up. See this:

[Ionic 2 Form goes up when keyboard shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161705/ionic-2-form-goes-up-when-keyboard-shows)